# Folder structure not visible in zip created by python

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7

I am writing a small python script to zip a file on linux.

on the same machine after creating the zip , when i did an

unzip -l temp.zip

i am able to see the content but when i am moving the file to windows , on a double click i am not able to see any folder inside the zip .

However if i extract it , am able to see those files inside the folder .

```
files=['/home/myfile.txt']
restoreZip = zipfile.ZipFile("temp.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for file in files:
        restoreZip.write(file)
restoreZip.close()
```

If i create the files using zip -r temp.zip /home/myfile.txt , I am able to see the directory structure on double click when i am moving to windows machine .

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?